# Reset State of sibling

Tags: flutter, dart, key

I'm trying to reset the value of a String (dropdownValue) of my DropdownButton class (SomeButton) from another class which is a sibiling. To be more precise, here is some code with comments

**Parent** (Contains both siblings)

```
class Parent extends StatelessWidget {
  const Parent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Stackoverflow(),
        SomeButton(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Dropdown Class** (contains dropdownValue which I want to reset from button class)

```
class Stackoverflow extends StatefulWidget {
  const Stackoverflow({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Stackoverflow> createState() => _StackoverflowState();
}

class _StackoverflowState extends State<Stackoverflow> {
  String? dropdownValue;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton2(
          items: someItems,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              dropdownValue = value as String;
            });
          },
          value: dropdownValue),
    );
  }
}
```

**Button** (onTap -> clear dropdownValue from upper class)

```
class SomeButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const SomeButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        // reset dropdownValue
      },
    );
  }
}
```

When I searched for solutions, keys might be an option. But to be honest, I never used keys and saw no explicit documentation for my kind of problem. Provider could also be used, but I had trouble with not initialize my dropdownValue, because I should be empty when no user interaction is done so far. I would appreciate any kind of help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use callback functions from your parent class.

```
    class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  const Parent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Parent> createState() => _ParentState();
}

class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {
  String? dropdownValue;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Stackoverflow(
          dropdownValue: dropdownValue,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              dropdownValue = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        SomeButton(
          dropdownValue: dropdownValue,
          onTap: () {
//reset dropdownValue to whatever you want
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I will check it, do you mean GlobalKey and FormState is also an good option?

Comment: I would recommend using State Management solutions like provider or bloc, but yes sure